# How to ship css?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm using a third party lib, which apparently forces me put some `css` in my `chord-diagram.component.css`. So basically I have my component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

const Circle = require('chord'); //third party lib
const Model = require('model');  //third party lib

@Component({
  selector: 'chord-diagram',
  templateUrl: './chord-diagram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chord-diagram.component.css'],
})
export class ChordDiagramComponent implements OnInit {
  private _JSON: string;


  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let circle;
    new Model(this._JSON).load().then(function (m) {
      circle = new Circle('#target', m);
      // console.log('circle', circle);
    });
  }

  @Input()
  set JSON(value: any) {
    this._JSON = value;
  }
}
```

And my template:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px" id="target"></div>
```

So now there is some css for the visualisation, which gets shown in `target`, but I've to put it into my `chord-diagram.component.css`. The problem seem to be that the CSS is not rightly scoped to the visualisation behind the `target` if I put it into the `chord-diagram.component.css`, as it is not properly applied. I wonder if this is the way how third party lib should enforce CSS? What is the common way to ship your styles in such cases? It just doesn't feel right to force me to copy their CSS into my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using angular cli you can update your .angular-cli.json's styles array to include your third party css.  For example in this case I was able to pull in prismjs's css using this method:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism.css",
        "../node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This solves part of the issue, but it seems that the 'third-party css' collides with some of the css of my framework (Foundation). I just wondered how would be the perfect way to scope the css of the third-party lib to just if self. I'm quite new to commons modules and not sure how I can report it back to the developer of the widget.